# Problem for get angle in the axis x, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, euler-angles

I have an problem, the arrowObject have an axis in x of 180 but get me by code 0

```
    startOrientation1 = arrowObject.transform.eulerAngles.x;
    currentAngle1 = startOrientation1;

    minOrientation1 = startOrientation1 - amplitudeX;
    maxOrientation1 = startOrientation1 + amplitudeX;
    rotation = new Vector3(currentAngle1, 180, 0);


private void RotateArrowVertical()
{
    if (up)
    {
        currentAngle1 += arrowSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        if (currentAngle1 > maxOrientation1)
        {
            up = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        currentAngle1 -= arrowSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        if (currentAngle1 < minOrientation1)
        {
            up = true;
        }
    }
    rotation.x = currentAngle1;
    arrowObject.transform.localEulerAngles = rotation;
}
```

I try everithing but i don't have solution

Comment: in general read the documentation on [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) in particular `... When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.`

Comment: and you once read from `eulerAngles` but assign to `localEulerAngles` .. was that intened?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `startOrientation1` value is incorrectly retrieved, so try this instead in your code:

```
startOrientation1 = arrowObject.transform.localEulerAngles.x;
currentAngle1 = startOrientation1;

minOrientation1 = startOrientation1 - amplitudeX;
maxOrientation1 = startOrientation1 + amplitudeX;
rotation = new Vector3(currentAngle1, 180, 0);
```